# When to use On/In/At?

Tags: prepositions

When should I use On/In/At?

I was In/At School? In/At Home?
See you On/In/At Monday?
I left the book In/At my parent's house?

Other use cases I cn't think of right now?

And why is there a distinction?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Gulzar, welcome to EL&U.  Your question belongs on our beginner/novice site English Language Learners.  Follow the link and post your question there, not forgetting to delete the one here. https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: THERE IS NO RULE. 

You'll need to learn each case - and for some of them, it will depend what part of the world you are in. (_at school_ in the UK _in school_ in the US). 

The choice of prepositions is one of the most distinctive and inexplicable features of a particular language. There are families of similar cases, but no general rule.

Answer (score 2):

There're a lot of different phrases where we have to use ***on, in, at***.

Quite often it's difficult to predict the use of these prepositions there.

The most general rule (but not absolute) is:

Define the location of the object.

If it is on some surface, use 'ON' 
(ON the wall/ floor/ table/ ceiling/ platform/ etc.).

If it is in some volume (space), use 'IN' 
(IN the office/ room/ box/ corner/ sun/ rain/ etc.).

If it is neither in nor on smth, use 'AT' (AT home/  work/ the airport/ the hotel/ etc.).

This general rule helps rather often.

For example, we can   differentiate:

ON Cuba (as an island) and IN Cuba (as a country)

IN the corner (as space) and AT the corner (as a meeting place)

IN the (high) grass and ON the (cut) grass

IN the book (inside it, between pages) and ON the book (its cover)